# Need to work this string in as a parameter in my url

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a filter script that ads a value to my url trough a set of checkboxes. Each checkbox group can only ad one value.

First click on a checkboxgroup looks like this:

```
/Network-CAT-cables?fss=yellow
```

Where the fss=yellow is the added parameter. A click on another chekcbox group would look like this:

```
/Network-CAT-cables?fss=yellow+cat6
```

If I check another checkbox in one of the above groups it replaces the previous value.

Now i need to add a parameter that looks like this:

```
&sps=d211av450240_2.0
```

If I set that as a value in the checkbox it kinda work. It ads the parameter and sort after it. And if i add a "normal" value it places before it. and that works too - like this:

```
?fss=yellow+cat5&sps=d211av450240_2.0
```

The problem is that when I have several of the new custom parameter in a group. In the other checkbox groups I can only have one value - and the chosen one replaces the old parameter. with the custom parameter I want to add it just ads on, instead of replaceing - like this.

```
?fss=yellow+cat5&sps=d211av450240_2.0+&sps=d211av450240_1.0
```

The correct outcome would have been

```
 ?fss=yellow+cat5&sps=d211av450240_1.0
```

I know this is because of the "&" in the parameter - but unsure how to work it out. I cant change the parameter either - and I know checkboxes are ment to be for multiple choices, but its like this for a reason.

My filterscript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
new function(settings) { 
var $separator = settings.separator || '&';
var $spaces = settings.spaces === false ? false : true;
var $suffix = settings.suffix === false ? '' : '[]';
var $prefix = settings.prefix === false ? false : true;
var $hash = $prefix ? settings.hash === true ? "#" : "?" : "";
var $numbers = settings.numbers === false ? false : true;
jQuery.query = new function() {
var is = function(o, t) {
return o != undefined && o !== null && (!!t ? o.constructor == t : true);
};
var parse = function(path) {
var m, rx = /\[([^[]*)\]/g, match = /^([^[]+)(\[.*\])?$/.exec(path), base = match[1], tokens = [];
while (m = rx.exec(match[2])) tokens.push(m[1]);
return [base, tokens];
};
var set = function(target, tokens, value) {
var o, token = tokens.shift();
if (typeof target != 'object') target = null;
if (token === "") {
if (!target) target = [];
if (is(target, Array)) {
target.push(tokens.length == 0 ? value : set(null, tokens.slice(0),     value));
} else if (is(target, Object)) {
var i = 0;
while (target[i++] != null);
target[--i] = tokens.length == 0 ? value : set(target[i],   tokens.slice(0), value);
} else {
target = [];
target.push(tokens.length == 0 ? value : set(null, tokens.slice(0),  value));
}
} else if (token && token.match(/^\s*[0-9]+\s*$/)) {
var index = parseInt(token, 10);
if (!target) target = [];
target[index] = tokens.length == 0 ? value : set(target[index],    tokens.slice(0), value);
} else if (token) {
var index = token.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
if (!target) target = {};
if (is(target, Array)) {
var temp = {};
for (var i = 0; i < target.length; ++i) {
temp[i] = target[i];
}
target = temp;
}
target[index] = tokens.length == 0 ? value : set(target[index],  tokens.slice(0), value);
} else {
return value;
}
return target;
};

var queryObject = function(a) {
var self = this;
self.keys = {};

if (a.queryObject) {
jQuery.each(a.get(), function(key, val) {
self.SET(key, val);
});
} else {
self.parseNew.apply(self, arguments);
}
return self;
};

queryObject.prototype = {
queryObject: true,
parseNew: function(){
var self = this;
self.keys = {};
jQuery.each(arguments, function() {
var q = "" + this;
q = q.replace(/^[?#]/,''); // remove any leading ? || #
q = q.replace(/[;&]$/,''); // remove any trailing & || ;
if ($spaces) q = q.replace(/[+]/g,' '); // replace +'s with spaces

jQuery.each(q.split(/[&;]/), function(){
var key = decodeURIComponent(this.split('=')[0] || "");
var val = decodeURIComponent(this.split('=')[1] || "");

if (!key) return;

if ($numbers) {
if (/^[+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]*$/.test(val)) // simple float regex
val = parseFloat(val);
else if (/^[+-]?[0-9]+$/.test(val)) // simple int regex
val = parseInt(val, 10);
}

val = (!val && val !== 0) ? true : val;

self.SET(key, val);
});
});
return self;
},
has: function(key, type) {
var value = this.get(key);
return is(value, type);
},
GET: function(key) {
if (!is(key)) return this.keys;
var parsed = parse(key), base = parsed[0], tokens = parsed[1];
var target = this.keys[base];
while (target != null && tokens.length != 0) {
target = target[tokens.shift()];
}
return typeof target == 'number' ? target : target || "";
},
get: function(key) {
var target = this.GET(key);
if (is(target, Object))
return jQuery.extend(true, {}, target);
else if (is(target, Array))
return target.slice(0);
return target;
},
SET: function(key, val) {
var value = !is(val) ? null : val;
var parsed = parse(key), base = parsed[0], tokens = parsed[1];
var target = this.keys[base];
this.keys[base] = set(target, tokens.slice(0), value);
return this;
},
set: function(key, val) {
return this.copy().SET(key, val);
},
REMOVE: function(key) {
return this.SET(key, null).COMPACT();
},
remove: function(key) {
return this.copy().REMOVE(key);
},
EMPTY: function() {
var self = this;
jQuery.each(self.keys, function(key, value) {
delete self.keys[key];
});
return self;
},
load: function(url) {
var hash = url.replace(/^.*?[#](.+?)(?:\?.+)?$/, "$1");
var search = url.replace(/^.*?[?](.+?)(?:#.+)?$/, "$1");
return new queryObject(url.length == search.length ? '' : search,         url.length == hash.length ? '' : hash);
},
empty: function() {
return this.copy().EMPTY();
},
copy: function() {
return new queryObject(this);
},
COMPACT: function() {
function build(orig) {
var obj = typeof orig == "object" ? is(orig, Array) ? [] : {} : orig;
if (typeof orig == 'object') {
function add(o, key, value) {
if (is(o, Array))
o.push(value);
else
o[key] = value;
}
jQuery.each(orig, function(key, value) {
if (!is(value)) return true;
add(obj, key, build(value));
});
}
return obj;
}
this.keys = build(this.keys);
return this;
},
compact: function() {
return this.copy().COMPACT();
},
toString: function() {
var i = 0, queryString = [], chunks = [], self = this;
var encode = function(str) {
str = str + "";
if ($spaces) str = str.replace(/ /g, "+");
return encodeURIComponent(str);
};
var addFields = function(arr, key, value) {
if (!is(value) || value === false) return;
var o = [encode(key)];
if (value !== true) {
o.push("=");
o.push(encode(value));
}
arr.push(o.join(""));
};
var build = function(obj, base) {
var newKey = function(key) {
return !base || base == "" ? [key].join("") : [base, "[", key,     "]"].join("");
};
jQuery.each(obj, function(key, value) {
if (typeof value == 'object') 
build(value, newKey(key));
else
addFields(chunks, newKey(key), value);
});
};

build(this.keys);

if (chunks.length > 0) queryString.push($hash);
queryString.push(chunks.join($separator));

return queryString.join("");
}
};

return new queryObject(location.search, location.hash);
};
}(jQuery.query || {}); // Pass in jQuery.query as settings object

function removeFSS() {
ga("send", "event", "button", "click", "filter-clear", "input");

var t = encodeURI(unescape($.query.set("fss", '')));
var n = window.location.href.split("?")[0]; window.location.href = n     + t
}
function getFSS() {
var D = jQuery('.filterGenius input, .filterGenius         select').serializeArray();
var O = {};
jQuery.each(D, function(_, kv) {
if (O.hasOwnProperty(kv.name)) {
O[kv.name] = jQuery.makeArray(O[kv.name]);
O[kv.name].push(clean(kv.value, ""));
}
else {
O[kv.name] =kv.value;
}
});

var V = [];
for(var i in O)
if(jQuery.isArray(O[i]))
V.push(O[i].join("+"));
else 
V.push(O[i]);

V = jQuery.grep(V,function(n){ return(n) });
return V.join("+"); 
}
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".filterGenius input").each(function () {
if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
$(this).attr("checked", "checked")
}
});
$(".filterGenius select option").each(function () {
if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
$(this).attr('selected', true);
}
});

$(".filterGenius input, .filterGenius select").change(function () { 

var s = encodeURI(unescape(jQuery.query.set("fss", getFSS())));
var o = window.location.href.split("?")[0];

$(".filterGenius input, .filterGenius select").attr("disabled", true);

window.location.href = o + s
});
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
$('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked',     false);
});

});
```

Comment: Indentation and relevant code only please

Comment: Why don't you use the `name` attribute of the checkbox groups to define the keys of your params? Also, please add the relevant HTML